# "Public relationship"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the author of this sentence (from a GRE practice test) mean by "public relationship"? :

> The governor has long been obsessed with excising the media from the politician **public relationship**. That's been the unifying aim of all her seemingly disconnected ventures since entering public life: a determination to erode, and eventually end, the media's hold on political communication.

Comment: Could you please provide the research you have done up to this point, and where exactly the confusion arises for you? Please include this in your question, as we can probably not answer it in its current form. Thank you!

Comment: It's poorly written, and one is tempted to assume that some word or punctuation has been omitted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, psosuna, Hot Licks. This is my first time to use this website, and I want to understand the meaning of this sentence. It would be appreciated if this sentence is rewritten so that non-native English speaker can understand. For example, "a determination to erode, and eventually end, the media's hold on political communication." is a difficult part for me, even though there is a colon and the last sentence has the same meaning in the sentence before colon, I cannot understand how they are connected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Thr sentence does not use the phrase "public relationship", but rather the phrase "politician public relationship", meaning "relationship between politician(s) and public(s)". It should preferably have a hyphen or en dash, as in "politician–public relationship".

Comment: Thank you very much, ruakh. This is great because just putting hyphen makes the sentence easier for readers. I really appreciate your comment.